# How-to include an optional Bag in my hbm.xml file?

Tags: spring, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

How do I make the Bag optional for class Test in the following pseudo hbm.xml?

```
<class name="Test" table="test">     

<bag name="bag" table="example" cascade="all" fetch="join">
        <key property-ref="key">
            <column name="a_id" />
            <column name="b_id" />
        </key>
        <element column="example_id" 
                type="my.myclass"/>
    </bag></class>
```

my.mclass is a custom type (my.myclass implements org.hibernate.usertype.UserType)

In the moment if there is no fitting "test example" row in the example table I get an exception?
(I was hoping to find a kind of not-found attribute? But there is no)

Answer (score 0):

What's the relationship between Test and myclass? 1 to many or many to many?

If it's 1 to many in your case, I will suggest you create separate mapping for myclass and use following mapping for Test class

```
<bag name="bag" table="example" inverse="true" cascade="all" fetch="join">
    <key property-ref="key">
    <column name="a_id" />
    <column name="b_id" />
    </key>
    <one-to-many class="my.myclass"/>
</bag>
```

Comment: my  problem is that my.mclass is a custom type not an entity. So I am not sure if this will work? my.myclass implements UserType